# Rotating Label inside ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, labeling

I would like to label a curve inside ListLinePlot. Let's say I have the following list:

```
Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}]
```

What I expected is a labeled curve. The label should also be placed above the curve and in the middle. It should also be rotated with the curve like the following picture.

[image]

But if I try the following code with ListLinePlot and Labeled:

```
ListLinePlot[Labeled[Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}], "x^2", {Top, Center}]]
```

[image]

And I get the following error:

```
Labeled::labpos: {{Top,Center}} is not a valid position for the placement of labels.
```

How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Version 11.0.1, Labeled can be used in the dataset level.

```
data = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];
ListLinePlot[Labeled[data, Style[Rotate[x^2, 40 Degree], Bold, 14], {6, 42}]]
```

The third argument of Labeled in this case is a precise location.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To use `Labeled` to make the kind of label you want, you have to wrap a specific point with `Labeled`. You also have to use `Rotate` to get the rotation.

Here is the code:

```
data = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];
data[[61]] = Labeled[data[[61]], Rotate[Style[x^2, 14, Bold], 40 °]];
ListLinePlot[data]
```

`data[[61]]` is the point `{6., 36.}`

[image: plot]

#### Update

You can nudge the label with `Labeled`'s 3rd argument. In the following example, I have moved the label somewhat closer to the curve.

```
data = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];
data[[61]] = Labeled[data[[61]], Rotate[Style[x^2, 14, Bold], 40 °], {.7, 0}];
ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks! That's quite what I wanted. But I think the label is a little to far away from the curve. Is there any way to make it a little bit nearer?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Text` or `Inset` in `Epilog`:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}], 
 Epilog -> Text[Style[x^2, 15], {4.5, 25}, Automatic, {1, .6}]]
```

or

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}], 
 Epilog -> Text[Style["x^2", 15], {4.5, 25}, Automatic, {1, .6}]]
```

depending on whether you want to math-format the exponent.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't one of these examples demonstrate the use `Inset`?